# Passing values to macros by for loop

Tags: c, visual-c++, macros

I want to pass values to the macro through `for` loop,but when i try to pass values it gives error, please help m as fast as possible. When values of `i` are passed to macro as Valve(i) it gives error

my code given below:

```
#define Valve(x) stTest.bValve##x##_Cmd

typedef struct OperationFlags
{
   int bValve1_Cmd;
   int bValve2_Cmd;
}FLAGS_TypeDef;

void main(void)
{
  FLAGS_TypeDef stTest;
  int j,i;

  stTest.bValve1_Cmd = 4;
  stTest.bValve2_Cmd = 9;

  for(i=1;i<=2;i++)
  {
    j=Valve(1);
    printf("%d",j);
  } 

}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please check the [FAQ - How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions, so that you get good answers. Requests like `Need a quick response` usually lead to the question being closed quickly. Also question is missing some information to get a good answer, especially what the error message is.

Comment: i am getting error    error C2039: 'bValvei_Cmd' : is not a member of 'OperationFlags'

Answer (score 2):

It is normal!
The preprocessor (the "thing" that processes the macros) is run BEFORE the C compiler. So, it is only valid when it produces compilable code.

In your case, if you use the code you show

```
j=Valve(1)
```

it will work for that value, since it will produce:

```
j=stTest.bValve1_Cmd
```

but it will do the entire loop only with that value.
When you change the parameter "1" with the "i" for actually doing the loop, then it will produce:

```
j=stTest.bValvei_Cmd
```

which is invalid.

To do what you want, just use a vector:

```
typedef struct OperationFlags
{
 int bValve_Cmd[2];
}FLAGS_TypeDef;
#define Valve(x) stTest.bValve_Cmd[x]
//....
for(i=1;i<=2;i++)
{
 j=Valve(1);
 printf("%d",j);
}
```

Comment: is there any other way than using array,because i want reduce my code size. so i need my flags to be in bit format i.e int bValve_Cmd:1;

Answer (score 0):

Macro replacement is done *well* before runtime, so you cannot use a variable `X` containing the value `2` to get `stTest.bValve2_Cmd`. Instead, you will get `stTest.bValveX_Cmd`, for which no symbol exists.

You will have to find another way of doing this, such as having an array of values for which you *can* use `X` to select:

```
#define Valve(x) stTest.bValveX_Cmd[x]

typedef struct OperationFlags {
   int bValveX_Cmd[2];
} FLAGS_TypeDef;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `#define Valve(x) (x == 1 ? stTest.bValve1_Cmd : stTest.bValve2_Cmd)`

---

`#define Valve(x) (*(&stTest.bValve1_Cmd + (x-1)))`

note : It may not work if the environment changes. Also it can not be used in the bit field.

add check

```
#define Valve(x) (*(&stTest.bValve1_Cmd + (x-1))); \
assert(offsetof(FLAGS_TypeDef, bValve2_Cmd) == sizeof(int))
```

Comment: This will works finely,i have posted only sample part of my whole code.There are more than 2 flags like bValve_Cmd.There are about 4-5 such flgas i am using in my code.please suggest me better way